# why is it that the photon incident on metastable state stimulates atom to go into ground state but not to even higher energy state?

Tags: laser, atoms

isnt it possible that photon incident on atoms at metastable state goes to further high energy state rather than the ground state? whilist there is always that stimulated emisson taking place. why ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the photon energy. Stimulated emission happens when the photon energy matches the energy difference between the metastable and ground state. Excitation happens if the photon energy matches the energy difference between the metastable and some excited state.

If you found a system where the metastable to ground and metastable to excited state had **exactly** the same energy, then you would indeed get both stimulated emission and excitation. The relative probabilities would have to be calculated from the wavefunction.